# Are those sentences grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Q1. Are those 8 sentences grammatical ones? or if not could you tell me?
Q2. Why do we use 1 instead of 3?  It seems both are similar but is there any meaning difference or any purpose?

1. I love it that he will resign.
2. I love it he will resign.
3. I love that he will resign.
4. I love he will resign.
5. Rumor had it that he will resign.
6. Rumor had it he will resign.
7. Rumor had he will resign.
8. Rumor had that he will resign.

With the verb *love*, for me as second language learner, sentence (1) can be paraphrased as **I love the situation(=the fact) that he will resign.** While, when it comes to the verb *had*, the sentence, **Rumor had the situation(=the fact) that he will resign.**, sounds bad.

Comment: Can you explain which you think are correct and which are not? Show us you've done some thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

**For the first half:**

None of them are strictly grammatical. The best way to say it would be:

> I love (the fact) that he's resigning.

or

> I love (the fact) that he's going to resign.

"The fact" is optional, but it is commonly used in these sorts of sentences.

**For the second half:**

None of them are correct; you are mixing the past tense with the future tense.

If you are talking about the past, you can use one of these:

> Rumour had it that he would resign.
>
> Rumour had it that he resigned.
>
> Rumour had it that he was going to resign.

If you are talking about the present:

> Rumour has it that he is resigning.
>
> Rumour has it that he is going to resign.